# How to compile LibVLC for Android 7?

Tags: android, android-studio, vlc, android-sdk-tools, libvlc

I might be asking a really dumb question (as I always feel whenever I have to ask something trivial), but I can't figure out how to compile libVLC for my specific version of the SDK.

I am following the AndroidCompile page from the wiki, everything works fine until gradle starts doing his thing. Then I realize that, even though I've fed him API 24 (which stands for Android 7), it's still trying to default to API 29 (Android 10, if I'm not mistaken).

So, what gives? Maybe I need to git clone an earlier branch? Tried that too, haven't found one for 24 specifically.

All I need is to set up an Android Studio project targetting API 24 and I need VLC in it. If I can do that without having to compile the stuff myself, that'd be even better. Right now I'm trying to get the official Android VLC sample app to compile, and I'm missing libvlc-3.0.0.aar. Hence the question.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you got the *minimum* and *target* SDK notions confused.

LibVLC (the library) currently requires a **minimum** SDK version of Android 17.

Your project (the app), which would reference LibVLC, needs a **target** SDK version of Android 24.

I don't see a problem here.

As for compiling LibVLC for Android, the easiest way is to use the docker image provided by VideoLAN, but from what I understand you don't need to.